# Is there a design tool that tells you what gauge of wire to use?

Tags: circuit-design, design, cables, wire

Do any circuitry design tools (5spice, etc.) have a feature that tells you what currents you'll have in each wire/cable, and recommend therefore which gauge of wire or type of cable to use for each branch of the circuit?

Comment: Normally you choose wire based on temperature rise or voltage drop specs based on length of pair then lookup AWG size

Comment: Wire sizing is not that straight forward. In addition to the above, the tolerable rise in temperature depends on the insulation of the wire, conductor material, ambient temperature, physical arrangement of the wire(s), air flow, and tolerance of surrounding components and structures

Comment: It really seems like given a certain application, there are certain assumptions that can be made. For example, in electrical panels to be used in a light industrial setting where ambient temperature is within everyday ranges... etc etc

Comment: @djg Yes, few projects have the resources or requirements stringent enough to actually calculate (more like simulate) it out so appropriate tables are used

Comment: Wire aware EDAs are very sparse and far between compared to PCBA, the tools that are out there  are usually very different from a typical PCBA workflow of schematic capture leading to pcb layout , one finds you still need to provide the mental glue logic for any wire based  process.  But I am surprised about one thing,  I feel It should be relatively straight forward to get modeling tools to spit out at least current by conductor and from there you can study the wire tables.

Comment: @crasic LTSpice does this.

Answer (score 3):

For most applications I would just use a chart like this and call it done:

https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

For applications where the cost, mass off the wire, or efficiency is very important, you should calculate the wire losses and decide what tradeoff you want to make.

For example:

Lets say I have an inverter which draws 100A at 12V. The chart says I should use 6awg wire for that, but lets say that seems overly large or expensive.

If there are 2 wires each 0.5M long, then the total resistance of the wires is 1.29mOhms (from the chart).

The voltage drop will be 1.29E-3 ohms * 100A = .129V

.129V * 100A = **13W**

From this we can determine that the wire will get fairly warm (you can use another calculation to estimate how warm). We can also determine that the reduction in efficiency will be approximately 13W/1200W = ~1%.

From here you can adjust the calculation for different wire diameters until you find a cost/heating/efficiency tradeoff you're happy with.

Answer (score 0):

For many applications, like the electrical panels you mention, we select a wire size and type for easy handling, and a size suitable for the connectors and terminal blocks we intend to use, rather than trying to find the smallest acceptable wire for the current in each circuit.

For circuits that will carry more current than our "standard" wire can safely handle, we will, of course, have to choose a larger wire sizen and we can find that recommended size in standard copper wire tables or electrical code ampacity tables..